# Codeigniter Why I can't load view from MY_Controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want every controller to have a method _render_page, which loads the master template and passes the data object.

My home controller class looks like this:

```
class Home extends MY_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index() {
        $data['title'] = "Site title";
        $data['the_view'] = 'welcome_message';
        $this->_render_page($this->layout, $data);
        //$this->load->view($this->layout, $data);  //This works ok..
    }
}
```

MY_controller class:

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    public $layout;
    public $viewdata;

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->layout = 'layout/master_template';
        $this->viewdata = null;
    }

    public function _render_page($view, $data=null, $render=false) {
        $this->viewdata = $data;
        $this->viewdata['the_view'] = $view;
        if($this->ion_auth->logged_in()) {
            $user_obj = $this->ion_auth->user()->row();
            $usr_data['username'] = $user_obj->username;
            $user_obj = null;
            $this->viewdata['usr_data'] = $usr_data;
        }
        $this->load->view($this->layout, $this->viewdata);  //The code crashes here
    }
}
```

When I browse to home controller I get nothing, just white screen no errors...

Answer (score 0):

See, you need to understand the flow going, 
 when you call your class home , it extends MY_Controller, CI will look for MY_Controller, the constructor of your MY_controller gets executed after which CI starts executing the constructor of your home controller then your default method of home controller,
so in order to make it work you need to call `_render_page()`-
change your MY_Controller like -

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    public $layout;
    public $viewdata;

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->layout = 'layout/master_template';
        $this->viewdata = null;
        $this->_render_page($this->layout, $data=null, $render=false);  // call your method 

    }

    public function _render_page($view, $data=null, $render=false) {
        $this->viewdata = $data;
        $this->viewdata['the_view'] = $view;
        if($this->ion_auth->logged_in()) {
            $user_obj = $this->ion_auth->user()->row();
            $usr_data['username'] = $user_obj->username;
            $user_obj = null;
            $this->viewdata['usr_data'] = $usr_data;
        }
        $this->load->view($this->layout, $this->viewdata);  //The code crashes here
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work either. Why would I call the render method in parent class constructor?

Comment: @user568021 correct me if i am wrong but if you dont call the method how will it get executed?

Comment: @user568021 you must be calling it somewhere, perhaps in child class

Comment: exactly. see the Home controller.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution: I'm calling _render_page in a wrong way.
Instead of this:

```
$this->_render_page($this->layout, $data);
```

I should call like this:

```
$this->_render_page('welcome_message', $data);
```

Of course, that's what this function is about - to load a master page and pass the view name as member of $data, so the master page will know which view to load.

Comment: atlast you had to call the method _render_page(). thats what i was saying!

Comment: Because the constructor gets automatically called which inturn calls _render_page() function , or else you had to manually call that method somewhere!

Comment: YES! Carefully read through my question and see my "Home" controller (which extends MY_Controller)...and look at the index method. Than see my answer and you will know what I was doing wrong.